Create multiples dates list for each level of a factor
I would like to create a data frame that would include a date list replicated by the levels of a factor.
I can create the list pretty easily
lst_dates<-as.data.frame(seq(as.Date("2024-05-07"), as.Date("2024-09-01"), by="days")).
lst_dates <- lst_dates %>% 
  rename(Date_nuit = 1)

I would like to replicate this list by 37 times which is the number of levels of my factor of my df$Lieu. The name of the level of this factor would be added in a new column in my lst_date.

Thx for your help!

I think you're looking for expand.grid, expand.grid(Date_nuit = lst_dates$Date_nuit, Lieu = unique(your_other_data$Lieu)).

As a minor point, I'd suggest not referring to things a "lists" unless they are list class objects. It can lead to confusion.

With only 2 data frames, you can also do a cross join, merge(lst_dates, data.frame(Lieu = unique(your_other_data$Lieu)), all = TRUE)
